# How to change connection string of an app.config file after deploying using clickonce

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, app-config

I want to change connection string of an app.config file as database connection string will be different on my client machine. If I make app.config file and deploy and after that when i change the connection string of the deployed app.config it gets changed but now when I install it shows me error. I come accross some solution which shows exclude app.config from hashing but that option is disabled. Please help

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859